# Is the converse of the statement "If partial derivatives exist and are continuous, then the function is differentiable at that point" true?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I know the proof of the statement *"If partial derivatives exist in a n-ball $B(\vec{a})$ and are continuous at $\vec{a}$, then the function is differentiable at $\vec{a}$ "* . But I was wondering whether the converse holds.

I was thinking along these lines that, differentiability at a point implies the existence of tangent plane, and that $\vec{a}$ lies on that plane. This would mean that the partial derivatives do exist, but I'm not able to visualize or proceed any further.

Comment: Hint: Do you know any examples of differentiable functions (of one variable) with discontinuous derivative?

Comment: @moishe Yes I do $f(x) = \begin{cases} 
  x^2 \sin(1/x) &\mbox{if } x \neq 0 \\
0 & \mbox{if } x=0. 
\end{cases}$, but I cannot visualize the whole thing in higher dimensions, let's say for 3D as to how it involves the tangent plane.

Comment: Then you have answered your own question: The converse to that theorem does not hold. No need for a visualization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have repututation for comment so I will post as answer.
The converse of your claim is not true even in dimension 1: differentiability in one point does not imply diffenentiability in any neighborhood of that point, see for example:

\begin{cases}x^2 \, \,\,\text{ if} &x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
It is differentiable at the origin and not continuous in any other point.
The same example works also in higher dimension.